# jquery searchable selection that is dynamically updated

Tags: jquery, ajax, dynamic, combobox

I am trying to use a single javascript selection box which is searchable, has a multiple selection option, and filters the remaining options based on previous options that were selected.  I've looked at Chosen, Selectize.js, typeahead.js, and a few others and they get close but I've yet to find a way to dynamically reduce the selection box options based on prior selections.

My data is very complex so here are two simple use cases
I have data which has country, state, and city/county.
The user should be able to take these different paths:
a) type usa, see USA as the only option, select it, then type 'Vir' and see virgin islands and virginia, see Virginia and select it, then type 'al' and see 'alexandria city' and 'albermarle county' then select 'alexandria city' and see some results tied to that in a table below.
b) type 'montgom' and see 'montgomery county' and select it, then when the user clicks in the box the only values they should see are USA for country and Virginia and Maryland (and any other states with that county name), then select 'Virginia' and get the results because there are no other combination of values that remain

The key functionality that I've not seen demonstrated anywhere I've looked is the dynamic updates to the values inside of the same selection box (or combobox depending on what you want to call it).  Lot's of examples show cascading selection boxes but I don't want those, as I already have that and it takes up a lot of room because of all the selection boxes I have to use (I have up to 8 different selection boxes depending on the particular use case).

I'm also curious as to how one would structure the state to support this.  Would it be a two column list of associations which goes on and on for every allowable combination (like a hacked version perhaps of a graph db relationship), or would it be 3 columns with: country, state, city/county which has all the allowable combinations?

I've spent a good portion of the day just googling this concept in all kinds of different ways like ontology search, taxonomy, dynamic hierarchical tagging (not quite this but I'd think it would be similar concept) but have yet to find a working example/demo or an explanation of how this would be done both in code and in DB structure.

In terms of technical details I'm running a MS T-SQL DB and ASP.net front end with some javascript/jquery/ajax code for other site features.

I appreciate any suggested links, reading, or other examples I should explore that perhaps I might have missed.  This just seems like something nobody else is looking for and maybe that's why I feel all alone on this.

Comment: Sounds like you may want to avoid a library as those are not likely to be built in a way that will easily support using one single select box for what are effectively multiple nested selections. You could roll your own solution using some Ajax and a couple data attributes to keep track of the selections as you drill down

Comment: The scope of this seems huge - and would require quite an undertaking to answer fully. Mostly SO is for things you've tried, encountered issues with, and can produce a [minimal, complete, and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example for us to reproduce the issue to help troubleshoot. That said, you could find a location API to get cities/counties/states/countries that match the input - and only show matching values; something like Google's Autocomplete for Addresses, so you don't have to reinvent the wheel in finding matching info (that specific API could get expensive though).

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example ([MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post your code here

Comment: @DelightedD0D - I've almost come to the same conclusion that its going to have to be a custom solution since I've not seen a functionality like this from any existing code

Comment: @mark.hch - the location is just an example to demonstrate the functionality, the data I'm using isn't location based and I already have all the data that supports the relationships needed to drive this, I just don't see whether or not this is even possible.

Comment: @JimmyAdaro - do you mean with code or with data?

Comment: @sony - I've tried the jquery/selection based extensions mentioned in my post but they don't offer this type of extension

Comment: just to clarify, I definitely am not asking for someone to do this for me without me trying any custom code myself, what I am trying to do is avoid investing a bunch of time into R&D for something that's not even possible so I'm more or less looking for someone who has seen a github based or other open source example of this being done which I've just completely missed somehow, or someone to say this can't be done with current javascript technology, or it can be done and you should consider looking at X to do it